# ActionBar color change also ListView color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionbar, background-color

sometring strange is happening in my app, when I try to change color of ActionBar by

```
<style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#DCDCDC</item>
</style>
```

is also changes color of my ListView and in other activity changes whole content below. Why is that? How to fix this?

ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/listviewbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty straight forward when it comes to overriding the [default color & styles of the action bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground).  I'm assuming that you're probably making changes to your application's resource styles file at *res/values/styles.xml*.  I'm also assuming that in your *AndroidManifest.xml*, you have the following property applied to the `application` tag:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Again, from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

> A style is a collection of properties that specify the look and format for a View or window. A style can specify properties such as height, padding, font color, font size, background color, and much more. A style is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML that specifies the layout.

So, when you change that *styles.xml* file, you're inadvertently changing the background color for all elements in your app.

Follow the instructions from the [link 1](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground), and you'll be good.  Specifically,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You`re rigth, I`ve checked that once again and it works. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you would kindly accept the answer the world will be a better place! ;)